# Questions on ergodicity

Tags: thermodynamics, probability, ergodicity

The "definition" of an ergodic system is that the average of its states in phase space is the same as its average over time. So I was thinking to myself

**Is a pendulum an ergodic system?**

In this case, I am talking about a pendulum with a given energy greater than zero, which is not subject to friction.

At first I thought that yes, it is indeed an ergodic system. But then I reconsidered. The trajectory of the pendulum in its $(\Theta,\dot{\Theta})$ phase space is an ellipsoid, whose "average" (=center of gravity?) is at the origin where $\Theta=\dot{\Theta}=0$, which is also the time-average of the pendulum's motion, which led me to the conclusion that it is, indeed, ergodic. However, the origin of the state space is a state which the pendulum will never visit. This made me doubt my conclusion, but I am still not 100% sure. So, does the pendulum qualify as an ergodic system, or does it not? Is my understanding of ergodicity correct in the first place? Is there something about ergodicity which I should know that I seemingly do not know already?

Comment: You have to use the Hamiltonian phase space $(\Theta,q_\Theta)$, not the Lagrangian phase space as you have done here.

Comment: @dmckee I do not understand what you mean by $(\Theta,q_{\Theta})$. Do you mean $(\Theta,p_{\Theta})$?

Comment: Yes. $p_\Theta$. Sorry.

Comment: @dmckee Thanks. But doesn't that result in an ellipsoid as well?

Comment: Well, you get a circle, which is an an element of the set of ellipsoids.

Answer (score 1):

The ergodic hypothesis holds that all the *accessible* states are equally likely under the right average (usually either a time average of a single system or an ensemble average).

But we have to consider what is meant by "accessible". In this case you have assigned the system a particular energy, so only states of that energy (or more properly a particular range of energies $[E,E+\Delta E)$ for small $\Delta E$) are included. The origin lies outside that energy range and *should* be excluded.